# Eclipse and Mysql Connection Error

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

Getting this error while connecting to Eclipse with mysql anybody could help.

Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended.

According to **MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+** requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting `useSSL=false`, or set `useSSL=true` and provide truststore for server certificate verification.

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'mydb'

```
package jdbcDemo;

import java.sql.*;
public class Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        //1. Creating Connection to a Database
        Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb", "root","bilmuj98");

        //2. Creating Statement
        Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement(); 

        //3. Execute SQL Query
        ResultSet myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("Select * from mydb.Employee");

        //4. Process the result set
        while(myRs.next())
        {
            System.out.println(myRs.getString("first_name") + "," + myRs.getString("last_name"));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {   
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: do you have mydb database in mysql?

Comment: Yes i have mydb in mysql.

Comment: According to that error, you don't have a database called `mydb`. So either you are connecting to the wrong server, or the name isn't `mydb`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass parameter `useSSL=true` in your mysql url like this:

```
 Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useSSL=true", "root","bilmuj98");
```

or try with

```
  Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8", "root","bilmuj98");
```

Comment: After adding this line i am getting this error. com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'mydb'
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

Comment: I have added one more suggestion